# Cannot find -lstatic

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, cmake

I'm trying to install ccurl-cli from this git repo:
https://github.com/iotaledger/ccurl/tree/master/src/cli

Following the README.md I get this error:

```
[ 10%] Linking C executable ccurld
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstatic
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/ccurld.dir/build.make:83: recipe for target 'ccurld' failed
make[2]: *** [ccurld] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/ccurld.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/ccurld.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have already built ccurl and added it in the library path in this way:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dario/ccurl
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I can find libstatic.a (-lstatic) nowhere.
It is only mentioned in file ccurl/src/cli/CMakeFiles/ccurld.dir/link.txt

> /usr/bin/cc   -rdynamic -Wl,-lpthread CMakeFiles/ccurld.dir/ccurld.o  -o ccurld -lstatic

Comment: The CMake file uses `${LIBRARY_NAME}static` which means it is supposed to be using `-lccurlstatic` but the `LIBRARY_NAME` variable is not set. Either it's a bug in the CMake config, or you're not following the instructions properly.

Comment: Also, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` deals with finding shared libraries *at run time*.  It is not typically related to finding development libraries at link time, or to static libraries at all.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWakely. The instructions say : "This requires iotaledger/ccurl to be built (done) and in the library path". My LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting is useless, according to JohnBollinger. So what should I do?

Comment: "So what should I do?" - Report the problem to the project's developers.